# How can I convert the FULL OUTER JOIN from Oracle SQL into MySql syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I've seen a few methods online to do this, but i couldn't manage to apply them in my case. I have 4 tables:

```
Suppliers(id_sup, name, city)
Companies(id_co, name, city)
Producuts(id_p, name, city)
Deliveries(id_sup, id_co, id_p)
```

What I need to do is do a query, where I get printed every city, only once, and for each city show the number of suppliers/companies/products that are there.
I managed (somehow) to do this in Oracle SQL:

```
SELECT coalesce(s.city,c.city,p.city) city,
            count(distinct s.id_sup) Suppliers,
            count(distinct c.id_co) Companies,
            count(distinct p.id_p) Products
FROM suppliers p
FULL OUTER JOIN companies c on s.city = c.city FULL OUTER JOIN products p on s.city=p.city
GROUP BY coalesce(s.city,c.city,p.city);
```

But I just don't know how to do this in Mysql. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the two duplicates I just added, they're much easier to understand.

Comment: Doesn't your MySQL version support FULL OUTER JOIN?